# replace value based on other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

There are two dataframe with same columns, index and the order of the columns are the same. I call them tableA and tableB.

```
    tableA = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[np.NaN,1,2],'col2':[2,3,np.NaN]})
    tableB = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[2,4,2],'col2':[2,3,5]})

    tableA                          tableB
               col1    col2                    col1    col2
          0      na       2               0       2       2
          1       1       3               1       4       5
          2       2      na               2       2       5
```

I want to replace some value of tableB to 'NA' where the value of same position of tableA is na.
For now, I use loop to do it column by column.

```
    for n in range(tableB.shape[1]):
        tableB.iloc[:,n] = tableB.iloc[:,n].where(pd.isnull(tableA.iloc[:,n])==False,'NA')

    tableB                         
               col1    col2            
          0      NA       2               
          1       4       5               
          2       2      NA
```

Is there other way to do it without using loop? I have tried using replace but it can only change the first column.

```
    tableB.replace(pd.isnull(tableA), 'NA', inplace=True) #only adjust the first column.
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

**1.**

```
df = tableB.where(tableA.notnull())
print (df)
   col1  col2
0   NaN   2.0
1   4.0   3.0
2   2.0   NaN
```

**2.**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(tableA.notnull(), tableB, np.nan), 
                  columns=tableB.columns, 
                  index=tableB.index)
print (df)
   col1  col2
0   NaN   2.0
1   4.0   3.0
2   2.0   NaN
```

Comment: Can None be filtered out by notnull?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But if have string `NA` need first `df = df.replace('NA', np.nan)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mask`

```
In [7]: tableB.mask(tableA.isnull())
Out[7]:
   col1  col2
0   NaN   2.0
1   4.0   3.0
2   2.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tableB[tableA.isnull()] = np.nan
```